# How to count cases with the same ID but different values on a second variable using SPSS?

Tags: spss

I have a problem with SPSS.  For instance, the person with `16` ID at the start of SPSS file is affiliated with both `boston scientific coorp` and `american water works`. Can I detect how many cases like this (in percentage and number)?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "cases like this"? Do you mean cases associated with those two companies, or cases associated with two companies? Do you want the percentage as a proportion of the rows in the database, ID numbers, companies or combinations of companies?

Comment: It has been already done by @Jeromy Anglim. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define duplicates based on the two variables: `data - identify duplicate cases` - Define matching cases by `personid` and `name`; this will create a new variable that identifies cases with the same `personid` and `name` combination
2. Apply a filter to exclude duplicates: `data -selecte cases`
3. Perform frequency analysis on `personid`: e.g., `analyze - descriptives - frequencies`